# How do ghostscript support PMingLiU?

Tags: c#, ghostscript

I use gsdll32.dll in my C# appication. (ghostscript version is 9.26)

But I have an error about converting a pdf to image.

This is the content of the pdf.

[image: image1]

And this image is the transformed content by ghostscript.

[image: image2]

The font of the pdf file is PMingLiU.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

-dGridFitTT=2

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied the original PDF file to look at, and you haven't supplied the back-channel output from Ghostscript, which makes it very hard to be certain what your problem is.

However I would guess that your problem is that the PDF flie may **request** 'PMingLiU' but it does not contain a copy of the font (or CIDFont). In this case Ghostscript will have supplied a warning on the back-channel, and used a substitute font. If the missing font is a CIDFont (as is likely) then it has a series of attempts based on likelihood of success. In this case it is probably falling back to its second-to-last option and using DroidSansFallback to replace the missing font.

You have two options to 'fix' this:

1) Create the PDF fiel with the font embedded. This is by far the best solution, is a requirement for CIDFonts (though many p[roducers ignore this) and is the **only** way to guarantee getting the correct output.

2) Supply Ghostscript with a better substitute font. To do this you will need to know whether the missing font is a Font or (more likely) a missign CIDFont. If its a missing Font then you need to modify fontmap.gs and add a substitute, if its a missing CIDFont then you need to edit cidfmap. You can either modify the copies in ghostpdl/Resource/Init or make new files. In either case you will need to tell Ghostscript which directory contains the copeis to use. You can do this by supplying the path using the -I switch.

Since you say this is your own application, and that you are using the Ghostscript DLL, may I draw your attention to the licence under which Ghostscript is supplied. This is the AGPL v3, so you must make your own application source code available (among other things) in order to comply with the licence.